# How to design a Bitter electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, design

I am designing electromagnets at my home and want to know how can I design electromagnets at home. [Bitter electromagnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_electromagnet) are really a challenge.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the construction and engineering of electromagnets. It seems more appropriate at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The real challenge is the power supply